# I need to know how to calculate the initial virtual runtime of a process in completely fair scheduler

Tags: scheduling

I am trying to implement a completely fair scheduler. I want to know how to calculate the initial value of virtual run time of a process in order to insert the process into a red black tree

Comment: Exactly what use do you have in mind? Understanding Linux's CFS? Replicating something similar in another kernel? Other? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the reserved word time to cause the timing statistics to be printed for the pipeline once it finishes AS in the manual of Bash as follows:

[time [-p]] [!] command1 [ | or |& command2 ]

The statistics currently consist of elapsed (wall-clock) time and user and system time consumed by the command’s execution. The -p option changes the output format to that specified by posix. When the shell is in posix mode (see Section 6.11 [Bash POSIX Mode], page 99), it does not recognize time as a reserved word if the next token begins with a ‘-’. The TIMEFORMAT variable may be set to a format string that specifies how the timing information should be displayed. See Section 5.2 [Bash Variables], page 73, for a description of the available formats. The use of time as a reserved word permits the timing of shell builtins, shell functions, and pipelines. An external time command cannot time these easily.

When the shell is in posix mode (see Section 6.11 [Bash POSIX Mode], page 99), time may be followed by a newline. In this case, the shell displays the total user and system time consumed by the shell and its children. The TIMEFORMAT variable may be used to specify the format of the time information.